# Is it possible to repair LEGO box creases?

Tags: sets, repair

Has anyone tried ironing or flattening a creased lego box to diminish the appearance of the damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since creases in cardboard are not mere folds but instead constitute real damage to the box, I don't think you can undo a crease to make it look new again. Even "sort of" straightening it out will not do much good for a box - the damage (compacted internal structure) will remain visible and the area will remain a weak spot for further damage to develop. Finally, the printing is likely also damaged in the creased spot and this damage will show clearly if you manage to straighten out the crease.